# Strava GPX upload changes activity hour

Tags: gpx, strava

I made a very small app which is generating a GPX for a 30 minute activity. (I am doing this because I do not have a waterproof device to track my swim)

I can upload it and the activity looks just like I intended.

Except one thing. It moved to 3 hours later. So when I upload it, all the times from the GPX file look like this: **2021-08-29T13:20:45Z** .

I have nothing in the timestamps outside of the 13:20 - 14:05 interval. Why does the Strava Activity say this: **4:20 PM on Sunday, August 29** instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format) article about the GPX format states:

> Dates and times are not local time, but instead are Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) using ISO 8601 format.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format)

Your local time probably experiences a 3 hour time difference to UTC

Answer (score 0):

A little addition to the accepted answer, particularly useful if you swim in different countries all over the world! ;)

If I understand correctly, your small app doesn't contain GPS data, so you have to check your profile settings and make sure your time zone is set properly.

As stated [here](https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/articles/216515918-My-activity-has-the-wrong-date-or-start-time) activities recorded indoors with no GPS data will default to the time zone of the location listed on your profile and sometimes Strava gets stuck when updating your time zone based on the location listed on your profile.

Comment: actually my app does contain GPS data, I am just making a "fake" route like locations: a->b->c->b->a->b->c->b->a. When I set these locations with my time intervals, I am generating a "constant" lap time for an indoor pool. distance(a->c) = 50m